# Finding sum of two integers in C

Tags: c, sum

I'm trying to get two numbers as input from the user, then print the sum of the two integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int number_one;
    int number_two;

    printf("Please enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", number_one);

    printf("Please enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", number_two);

    printf("The sum of the two numbers is: %d", number_one + number_two);
}
```

But when I run the program, it only asks for the first number, then stops running:

```
>> a.exe
Please enter the first number: 10
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf` expects a int-pointer, not a int. That's exactly what your compiler should tell you when compiling with enabled warnings.

Comment: Your compiler should be issuing warnings for that code. If not then you need to enable more warnings. And treat them as errors.

Comment: And please take a closer look at your learning material and what is says about `scanf` and its arguments.

Comment: This is not so much a failure to read up on scanf() as it is a basic misunderstanding of how arguments are COPIED into parameters.  If you understand that 'foo(type bar)' cannot mutate 'bar', such errors are much more unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

that happens many times in my editor try putting an & symbol at after the comma at the scanf
and you can assign a third variable to shorten an make your work more readable

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a, b , c;
printf("Enter number: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%d",&b);
c = a+b;
printf("your answer is: %d",c);

return 0;
}
```